# Youtube video embedding not working with react native on android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

My code for embedding a youtube video in a React Native app:

```
export class Signup extends React.Component {
  videoToPlay='https://www.youtube.com/embed/f7PlSUQiISY'
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          style={styles.WebViewContainer}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          source={{uri: this.videoToPlay}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 300,
  },
  video: {
  },
});
```

It shows up and lets me press Play on it, but after a split second of loading, tells me the video *is unavailable*...

From research, this is only an android issue it seems [I don't have a MacOS emulator installed yet to test on an iPhone emulator]. I've tried a couple of third party frameworks to get this working, like [this](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube) framework, but even after getting an API key, and following the tutorial in the readme **EXACTLY** it still just error'd out.

I also tried [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5video)... but no prevail

The only other thing I can think of is to load the webpage of the video, crop it to video size, then disable scrolling, but **Disabling scrolling in React Native doesn't seem to work if the site is youtube!** [ `scrollEnabled={false}` ]

I really need help with this, because I need videos to play in this app but would rather them not be local since the app is going to features potentially 10s to 100s of videos...